# Can we break surface tension without physical contact?

Tags: surface-tension

It's my understanding that surface tension is caused by hydrogen bonding. My question is whether or not we can break that bond, without physical contact. Could we use electricity, light, heat, or magnetic forces to remove that surface tension? A specific example would be a test tube of distilled water. Could one of those processes be used to break the surface tension along the walls of the tube?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't remove the entire surface tension and still have a surface (without tension the water will just atomise under thermal fluctuations and vaporise).

But you can certainly *reduce* the influence of hydrogen bonds and thus surface tension. Heating up the water is the simplest method - it will drown out the enthalpic contributions of the hydrogen bonds with entropy. And a sufficiently strong electric field would cause the electric dipoles of the water molecules to align with the field thus reducing hydrogen bonding.

I doubt radiation would have any effect since surface tension is virtually independent of pH.

Answer (score -1):

All water in liquid form has some surface tension. This inter-molecular attraction can be weakened by the kinetic energy of the water molecules i.e. heat. Thus, you can be heating the water.